# Rails 5 DB Migration error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to deploy my rails app to production but I am getting an error when trying to call `rake db:migrate` the error I get is `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Illegal parameter data type bigint for operation 'get_lock': SELECT GET_LOCK(2398406209365187035, 0)` I cannot see which migration is causing this and none of my migrations have the :limit set to convert to `bigint` from `integer`

This deployed fine in staging so I am not sure where the issue lies.

My migrations are as follows:

```
class CreateDatabase < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "vuln_sets", id: :integer, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
      t.string "vulntype", null: false
      t.string "displayname", null: false
      t.string "bulletinfamily", null: false
      t.integer "vulncount", default: 0, null: false
      t.boolean "active", default: false, null: false
      t.timestamp "timestamp", default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }, null: false
      t.index ["vulntype"], name: "vulntypeindex", unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Second migration:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Are these the only two migrations in your db? No other ones with bigInt?

Comment: Can you please add the command you try to run and the whole error message include the stack trace (you might need to add --trace to the command to get the whole stack trace).

Comment: Try to comment out migrations code. Binary search debugging approach :)

Comment: It's strange because GET_LOCK() takes in a string, not a number. That's what it's complaining about. `SELECT GET_LOCK("2398406209365187035", 0)` would have worked. It must be an old gem causing issues. Post the stack trace so we can see where this error pops up.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade Rails to 5.1.6.

Issue fixed by: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31521

Answer (score 4):

I've ran into this issue today. Seems like MySQL/MariaDB implementation of `get_lock` has changed:

On MariaDB 10.2:

```
> select get_lock(1234567890, 0);
+-------------------------+
| get_lock(1234567890, 0) |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
+-------------------------+
```

On MariaDB 10.3:

```
> select get_lock(1234567890, 0);
ERROR 4079 (HY000) at line 1: Illegal parameter data type bigint for operation 'get_lock'
```

Comment: I am getting this issue when I upgrade to rails 5.1.0